# PHP Login via sessions doesn't work on first attempt (in new window)

Tags: php, authentication, session

So I'm working on an application that requires a user to login before accessing any 'sensitive material'.

The login script works like this: User enters U/P->Script validates data->If valid, SESSION variables are set.

This is a very strange problem, since SESSIONS are handled by the server.

The problem:  When first opening the script in a new window or tab, submitting the login form takes you right back to the login form.  All subsequent requests work as expected!

Any ideas?

Comment: After the age of 18, my psychic abilities went away. Can you post your code?

Comment: I'll second the code request.  When a user submits the form, are they taken to a different page or does the form just POST to the same URL?

Comment: http://pastie.org/822527

Comment: I can nowhere see you writing to $_SESSION. Is this done in login_classes.php ? If so you'll need to post that too.

Answer (score 0):

$5 says `$auth->userAuth()` is where session values are getting set, and guessing that was supposed to be `!$auth->userAuth()` for a "password doesn't match" case.  The logic is kind of overlapping itself though.

Try this instead, just sorting the logic into separate blocks:

```
if ($action == 'login') {
    // all of the pre-authentication error checking first
    if (!$auth->emailExists($username)) {
        header('Location: index.php?action=unknownuser');
    } else if (!$auth->isAccountActive($username)) {
        header('Location: index.php?action=inactive');
    }

    // then actual authentication here - any errors have already redirected
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $auth->userAuth($username, $password);
    // opinionated bonus: adds clarity & keeps superglobals out of your classes
    // (you'll have to take them out yourself though)

    // and finally redirect on success/failure
    if (!$_SESSION['loggedin']) header('Location: index.php?action=authfailed');
    else header('Location: services.php');
}
```

Comment: yes the $_SESSION['loggedin'] variable is set to true in the userAuth method.